# Java "this", meaning

Tags: java, class, this

quick question about what this class is returning

```
public static class IndexLinearizer {
    int numFeatures;
    int numLabels;

    public IndexLinearizer(int numFeatures, int numLabels) {
        this.numFeatures = numFeatures;
        this.numLabels = numLabels;
    }
```

The variable IndexLinearizerer, what does it return?

Say for example numFeatures = 5 and numLabels = 2.

Does it return two objects, such as = 5, 2.

Sorry folks I'm really new to Java but and familiar with Python. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: That is not a variable.

Comment: How Sotirios already said, It's not a variable. It's the constructor of the class which gets called when you create a new instance.

Comment: Please ensure you complitelly understanding before you'll go in java deeper.
IndexLinearize is class. With one public constructor. Instances of this class have 2 fields (not variables) - numFeatures and numLabels, both of type int.
After constructor call you'll got instance of object.
Variables - is about methods body, not about objects itself.